# based on unnamed style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a small problem in my wpf application. I have two classes `GameObject` and `Block`. Both are `CustomControl`s, `GameObject` derives directly from `Control` and `Block` derives from `GameObject`. I want to write a style to block which will be based on the `GameObject` style. Here is a piece of code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:GameObject}" x:Key="game">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type primitives:GameObject}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=Row, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=Column, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:Block}" BasedOn="{StaticResource game}"> 
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type primitives:Block}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, if I added a `x:Key` to the first style, it wouldn't be automatically applied to every instance of `GameObject`, so my Style is useless in other files in program. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still apply it to both all and specific, you just need a global style that referances it.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:GameObject}" x:Key="game">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type primitives:GameObject}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=Row, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=Column, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:Block}" BasedOn="{StaticResource game}"> 
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type primitives:Block}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:GameObject}" BasedOn="{StaticResource game}">
</Style>
```

BasedOn has some definite possibilities if you need to apply a named style within a scope (object.resources) or globally.